# call a shell script by using a variable

Tags: shell, variable

I have a shell script, that will internally call a variable (that stores a executable shell script)

*Shell script starts*

```
var=$(awk -F'|' '{print $2}' $TEMPFILE)
```

The value in the variable is `. /lapp2/Scripts/mdm.ksh`

*execute the shell by calling it*

```
$var
```

The above method to execute a shell fails (is it reading as string?)

However, if I write the command directly, the shell scripts executes

Comment: So given that `[[ $var == "./lapp2/Scripts/mdm.ksh" ]]`, you should be able to simply invoke `$var`.  What exactly happens when you try to do this?  What is the output of `echo "var is '$var'"` and the error message presented by invoking `$var`?

Comment: Works for me. `echo 'echo hello, world' >hw.sh; var='. hw.sh'; $var` → `hello, world` just as expected. So, what error message(s) do you get when you try to use `$var` to source the script?

Comment: Parthi, do you intend the space between the leading dot and the `/app2/Scripts/mdm.ksh`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti yes i call using when i try to call it gives a error saying 'not found [No such file or directory]' , if i pass the command directly the it executes

Comment: yes it was intended one @roaima

Comment: How exactly do you invoke the action? Is it just `$var` on a line by itself? As @DopeGhoti asks, immediately before you invoke it, please add the line `echo "var is '$var'"` to your script, and provide the output and any immediately subsequent error message in your question.

Comment: VAL IS  : '/etlapp2/$1/mdm/Scripts/mdmxftpg.pl /etlapp2/$1/mdm/Scripts/mdmxftpg.aimtlane'                                                  and the script execution fails as                /etlapp2/fit/mdm/Scripts/mdmxftpg.pl /etlapp2/fit/mdm/Scripts/mdmxftpg.aimtlane: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: if i execute this seperately like this, it runs      - /etlapp2/fit/mdm/Scripts/mdmxftpg.pl /etlapp2/fit/mdm/Scripts/mdmxftpg.aimtlane

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `$var` doesn't contain the value you say it should contain. According to your question it should contain this:

```
. /lapp2/Scripts/mdm.ksh
```

But the debugging value from `echo "var is '$var'"` shows that `$var` actually contains:

```
/etlapp2/$1/mdm/Scripts/mdmxftpg.pl /etlapp2/$1/mdm/Scripts/mdmxftpg.aimtlane
```

There are two issues here. There's the obvious one that the actual value isn't the expected value. But more subtly, notice that `$var` contains a literal `$1` in part of the path instead of an interpolation of the first command-line argument. I suspect you have used single quotes instead of double quotes at some point during the assignment of `$var`.

Contrast these two alternatives

- `a='apple'; var='/path/to/$a/script.sh'; echo "var=$var"    # incorrect`
- `a='apple'; var="/path/to/$a/script.sh"; echo "var=$var"    # correct`

You need to review your code to find out why the value isn't as expected and to fix these errors.

Comment: I am finding hard to put the details here and format, so trying to explain it again

Comment: This is the shell script to be executed that is stored in the variable: . /etlapp2/fit/mdm/Scripts/mdmxpcmd.ksh unicode ENT_CORP_MDM wf_r_time_rd_qis_specx

Comment: The above command doesnt run/execute if called through variable, but runs if i leave it directly inside a shell script

Comment: @Parthi, no that's not what's in the variable. Look again at my answer that uses information you yourself supplied. There is a literal two-character string `$1` in the variable that should have been previously evaluated out.

Comment: yes i have editted the question now

Comment: @Parthi now you've taken all the other useful information out of your question, please re-run the script with the debug line in it `echo "var is '$var'"` and include that information literally. Don't paraphrase it. Write it exactly as it comes from the debug line.